# Do I need to nest my data to have a key (d3 csv reusable chart)?

Tags: csv, d3.js, nested

I seem to be having some key issues with an enter,update, exit chart. My data() function is having all kinds of trouble tracking the insertion and removal of data, and the scaling and removing and appending are not behaving properly.

[I've made a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4Iey3xdFhUPgzjoECN4?p=preview).

I am trying to make the chart update to display different data by year. The year divs can be clicked.

Do I need to nest my data? Is there a better solution?

Alternatively, is the best practice to create a separate update() function or to re-run the chartdraw() function?

Please excuse the janky code. Still figuring this out :)

Comment: It would help just describing what you are trying to accomplish first. What are you specifically having issues with?

Comment: As shown in the plunkr, I am trying to create a chart that displays different data by year. The data() function is struggling to tell the difference between previous states, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it doesn't look like you have an update for either the barsBars or barsText. Changes are only triggered on enter and exit.

Try adding this between the 'barsBars = svg.selectAll...' and 'barsBars.enter()...' lines:

```
barsBars
  .transition()
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {   
    return xScale(d.funded_month) + marginleft;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - yScale(d.value);
  })
  .attr("width",  barwidth - .2)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
  var picker = d.value / 138579040 + 100;
  picker = parseInt(picker)
  barColor = "rgb(40, 80, " + picker + ")";
  return barColor;
});
```

And this between 'barsText = svg.selectAll...' and 'barsText.enter()...' lines:

```
barsText
  .transition()
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.funded_month) + marginleft + xAdjust;
//return xScale(i) + barwidth / 2;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
     return h - yScale(d.value) - 2;
});
```

The .transition() lines are not necessary but they change how the graph updates. Try commenting them out to see the difference.

See Mike Bostock's general update patterns examples for more:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

Comment: Thanks. You are right I am relying just on enter and exit. I didn't realize I needed to also delineate code for transition(). I tried in the Plunkr and VOILA. Thank you.